# Unable to switch Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I don't get it. One moment it work, and the next, it stop working.

Main class :

```
public class QuotesDatabaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView tvQuotes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tvQuotes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuotes);
        tvQuotes.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent i = new Intent(QuotesDatabaseActivity.this, QuotesMain.class);
        startActivity(i);
        //Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(QuotesDatabaseActivity.this, QuotesMain.class);
        //startActivityForResult(startNewActivityOpen, 0);

    }
```

My AndroidManifest.

```
   <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".QuotesDatabaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".QuotesMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

It's just as simple as that and it doesn't switch screen. It did previously. No errors at logcat either.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The code which will work for you:

```
 public class QuotesDatabaseActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView tvQuotes;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tvQuotes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuotes);
    tvQuotes.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void onClick(View v)
    {
         if(v.getId()==R.id.tvQuotes)
         {

                 Intent i = new Intent(QuotesDatabaseActivity.this, QuotesMain.class);
                 startActivity(i); 
         }
   }
```

Comment: Tried. And still unable to work :( Is there anything that will affect the Intent/Activity function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way . I think it help you.

```
tvQuotes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(QuotesDatabaseActivity.this, QuotesMain.class);
        startActivity(i);


    }
});
```

---

or In you `onClick` method write this code.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.tvQuotes)
{
Intent i = new Intent(QuotesDatabaseActivity.this, QuotesMain.class);
        startActivity(i);
}

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Tried. And still unable to work :( Is there anything that will affect the Intent/Activity function?

Comment: please check out the source code..http://code.google.com/p/stackoverflowsample/. I am modify your code and solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

in place of `startActivity(i);` , Put this `startActivityForResult(intent,0);`

Comment: Tried. And still unable to work :( Is there anything that will affect the Intent/Activity function?

Comment: may be there is some code in other activity means in QuotesMain which effect this,do one thing pass intent to some other activity inplace of this QuotesMain activity and than check what happens

Comment: Guys, I got the code to work. Apparently, there's a redundant code in my next Activity that stops the screen from coming up. Fixed it. Thanks you guys for all your help!(:

Comment: hmmmm congrats i told u what ur QuotesMain activity might contain some error...any where congrats again

Answer (score 0):

Check whether which activity is launched since as per your code onCreate will be called and it start the activity.When you have to launch the new activity whether by clicking any components

Also check whether you have given finish() in new activity. If you didnt get solution please post the your requirement. I will try to give solution as possible.

Comment: It used to work. Then it stop working. I don't recall changing the code at this part. Does the widget affect this in any way?